# Python - View bot?

Tags: python, web, authentication, urllib2

I'm trying to write some code for viewbot.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib
import urllib
import argparse, os, time
import urllib.parse, random

headers = {
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Mobile Safari/537.36'
    }
login_data = {
    'login': 'xxx',
    'pass': 'xxx',
    'back_url': '' 
    }
```

Login on site works correctly.

Lists people:

```
def getPeopleLinks(page):
    links = []
    for link in soups.find_all('a'):
        url = link.get('href')
        if url:
            if 'profile/' in url:
                links.append(url)
    return links
```

Working...

And other code:

```
with requests.Session() as session:
        url = "https://xxxxxx.com/Login/?form_login=1"

        post = session.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
print (post.status_code)
print (post.cookies)
r = session.get("https://xxxxxxx.com/online/GIRL")
print (r.status_code)
print (r.cookies)
soups = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
x = getPeopleLinks(soups)
print(x)
print("http://www.xxxxx.com"+ x[2])
for link in x: 
        urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.xxxxxxx.com"+link)
print(link)
```

Login: Works correctly.
List of online users: Works correctly; I get all list of profiles.

I think it's a problem here:

```
for link in x: 
        urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.xxxxxxx.com"+link)
print(link)
```

I was logged in on another account by mobile, my profile was on the list, but the bot on the PC did not view my profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the problem in the syntax of the url.
Or maybe because of there might be an issue in this particular code, try this:

```
import urllib.request
for path in paths:
    url = 'http://example.com/view-online-profiles/' + path
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    print(page.read())
```

Or you can also follow another way:

```
import requests
for path in paths:
    url = 'http://example.com/view-online-profiles/' + path
    page = requests.get(url)
    print(page) # Would return response object, can obtain status_code or body
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on how platform is counting views. In cases of modern web apps the odds a high that it's not about HTTP request, but rather time spent + browser activity, that been tracked via JS code on page.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So i need to open webrowser, its impossible to do in only program?

Comment: That's a massive field, most popular way to control browser programatically is https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html . But again, this is just hypothesis on "why it's not working"